# Which mode (Sampled / Instrumented) in a memory profiler should I use to be sure I got rid of a memory leak in Java?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, visualvm, memory-profiling

My Java app is experiencing a memory leak which I am trying to tackle. However depending on which mode I select during the profiling run I get opposite results. Consequently I am not sure the memory leak I targeted has been solved since moreover an "Out Of Memory Error : Java Heap Space" recently spurt out in production.

Visual Studio Code [has a guide to understand the difference between the two modes (Sampling / Instrumentation or Tracing Profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/understanding-performance-collection-methods-perf-profiler?view=vs-2019) and there is also this [Ninjas' guide about the same topic on VisualVM](https://engineering.talkdesk.com/ninjas-guide-to-getting-started-with-visualvm-f8bff061f7e7). I understand that with the instrumented mode the overhead is much higher. But this modes is required (at least in Netbeans profiler) to get the list of the objects that have the highest number of "surviving generations" which is the indicator to watch in order to see the efficiency of the counter-measures that fight against a memory leak.

Thanks to the OOM stack trace I have a clue which method caused the memory leak and so I was able to isolate it in a unit test.

My unit test starts with `@RunWith(JfxTestRunner.class)` to avoid errors regarding "toolkit not initialized errors" when something is sent to the Java Fx App Thread (ie when something is shown to the user in the GUI app).

Now if I launch this unit test (loop that reads the content of a Solr index and populates a List based on this content) and profile it in sampling mode I get the following graph :

[image: Memory shape in sampled profile]
[image: Objects in memory in sampled profile]

This makes me think the problem is solved since the heap used increases during the index reading and decreases afterwards.

But now if I run the very same test in Instrumented mode with all classes (see "*" below), I get a very different memory shape :

[image: Memory shape in instrumented profile]
[image: Objects in memory in instrumented profile]

This time the used heap keeps increasing over time as if there were still a memory leak.

I first used the instrumented mode in order to get the objects that were keeping surviving garbage collections and then without paying attention I switched to the sampling mode and thought the problem had been solved. Now I am quite unsure.

Consequently I wonder which mode (Sampled / Instrumented) I should base my assessment on, and why such differences appear (memory footprint is higher in instrumented mode and surviving generations are approximately heighfold greater in this mode).

Any help appreciated,

Kind Regards